# RxJava: Create ordered sequence of onNext Calls

Tags: java, rx-java

Is there a Reactive idiomatic way to do the following:

```
obs.subscribe((e) -> {
  obs.onNext("BAR");
})
obs.onNext("FOO");
```

Which is to say: call obs.onNext, and when its done, call obs.onNext again with a new event object.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `Observable` work differenty. It can emit any amount of events (passed to `Subscriber`'s `onNext`) and only one `onCompleted` event. Once it sends onCompleted, the `Observable` ends and therefore cannot emit any more events.

There is nothing, that prevents you from creating a specified `Observable`:

```
Observable.create((subscriber) -> {
    if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
        return;
    }
    subscriber.onNext("FOO");
    subscriber.onNext("BAR");
    subscriber.onCompleted();
});
```

In this case, once subsribed, emits two events and completes it's work.

If you would like to dynamically add events to `Observable` I would suggest [`PublishSubject`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/PublishSubject.html). Example:

```
PublishSubject<String> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
publishSubject.subscribe(o -> {
    //Do whatever you want with o of type String
});
publishSubject.onNext("FOO");
publishSubject.onNext("BAR");
publishSubject.onCompleted();
```

Comment: I'm looking for a good way to ensure that `onNext("FOO")` happens, followed by `onNext("BAR")`, without nesting the handlers...